# Unrar a file in custom folder

Tags: batch-file

Am trying to extract a RAR file to a directory (C:\autoexe\source). Here the "autoexe" folder name changes everyday. The fullname does not change, the constant thing is "auto" in the string "autoexe", the exe part changes. I tried the below

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b "%cd%\samples\package.rar"') do start "" "%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" x -ibck "%cd%\samples\package.rar" *.* "%cd%\auto * \source"
```

Comment: Sorry if there's a mistake from my side. And again sorry if I have wasted your time here. The code works fine if the destination directory is constant like :for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b "%cd%\samples\package.rar"') do start "" "%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" x -ibck "%cd%\samples\package.rar" *.* "%cd%\autoexe\source"

Answer (score 1):

This commented batch code with error handling should do the job:

```
@echo off
rem Get name of first non hidden subfolder starting with auto in current folder.
for /D %%I in (auto*) do set "FolderName=%%I" & goto CheckArchive

echo Error: There is no auto* folder in: "%CD%"
echo/
pause
goto :EOF

:CheckArchive
if exist "samples\package.rar" goto ExtractArchive

echo Error: There is no file "package.rar" in subfolder "samples" of
echo        folder: "%CD%"
echo/
pause
goto :EOF

:ExtractArchive
"%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\UnRAR.exe" x -c- -idq -y -- "samples\package.rar" "%FolderName%\"
if not errorlevel 1 goto :EOF

echo/
echo/
pause
```

Read text file `Rar.txt` in program files folder of **WinRAR** for details on the used switches on `UnRAR` command line or run `UnRAR.exe` from within a command prompt window without any option to get displayed a brief help on how to use this freeware console application.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `set /?`

Read answer on [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) for an explanation of `&` operator. And read the Microsoft support article [Testing for a Specific Error Level in Batch Files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/69576).